# Particular integral of linear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm facing a problem solving the particular integral of linear partial differential equation below:$$(2D^2-5DD'+2D'^2)z = 5\sin(2x+y).$$

Here I tried to solve it in the way below:$$F(D,D')z = f(ax+by)$$ 
$$\text{here } F(a,b) = 0;$$
$$\text{so, } P.I. = {(x^2)\over (1^2)*2!} \cdot 5\sin(2x+y).$$

But in my text book the they solved it another way :$$(2D^2-5DD'+2D'^2) = (D-2D')(2D-D').$$

What is the real approach?

Answer (score 1):

$$2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}-5\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 5\sin(2x+y)$$
is an inhomogeneous PDE.
$$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}-2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left( 2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)z(x,y)=5\sin(2x+y)$$

Solving the associated homogeneous PDE : $\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}-2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left( 2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)Z(x,y)=0$
$$Z(x,y)=f(2x+y)+g(x+2y)$$
with any differentiable functions $f$ and $g$.

Search for a particular solution of the inhomogeneous PDE:

We could use the method of variation of parameter in searching a solution of the form $z=h(x,y)Z(x,y)$. This would be tiresome. By luck the form of the term $5\sin(2x+y)$ is the same as $f(2x+y)$.

So, it is much simpler to search a solution on the form: $c_1\:x\sin(2x+y)+c_2\:x\cos(2x+y)$. Putting it into the PDE allows to identify $c_1=0$ and $c_2=-\frac{5}{3}$. Thus, the general solution of the PDE is :
$$z(x,y)=f(2x+y)+g(x+2y)-\frac{5}{3}\cos(2x+y)$$
with any differentiable functions $f$ and $g$.